# Passing default arguments to class based views

Tags: python, django, django-views

Im trying to come up with a basic CRUD, nested resource implementation, with the following urls:

I cant figure out how to pass a default argument (the content type id, in my case) to the view. Below is what Ive used. Any pointers to accomplish this, or if this is total crap, any better way to accomplish this?

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
   url (
       regex = '^/?$',
       view =  ParentResourceListView.as_view(),
       name = 'parent_resource_list'
   ),

   url (
       regex = r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$',
       view =  ParentResourceDetailView.as_view(),
       name = 'parent_resource_detail'
   ),
   url (
       regex = r'^new/$',
       view =  ParentResourceCreateView.as_view(),
       name = 'parent_resource_create'
   ),

   url (
       regex = '^(?P<pk>\d+)/delete/$',
       view =  ParentResourceDeleteView.as_view(),
       name = 'parent_resource_delete'
   ),
   url (
       regex = '^(?P<pk>\d+)/edit/$',
       view =  ParentResourceUpdateView.as_view(),
       name = 'parent_resource_update'
   ),
)


urlpatterns += patterns('',
                   url (
    regex = r'^(?P<object_id>\d+)/child_resources$',
    view =  ChildResourceListView.as_view(),
    name = 'parent_resource_child_resource_list',
    kwargs = {
        "content_type",
        ContentType.objects.get_for_model(ParentResource).id
        }
    ),
                   url (
    regex = r'^(?P<object_id>\d+)/child_resources/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',
    view =  ChildResourceDetailView.as_view(),
    name = 'parent_resource_child_resource_detail',
    kwargs = {
        "content_type",
        ContentType.objects.get_for_model(ParentResource).id
        }
    ),
                   url (
    regex = r'^(?P<object_id>\d+)/child_resources/new/$',
    view =  ChildResourceCreateView.as_view(),
    name = 'parent_resource_child_resource_create',
    kwargs={
        "content_type",
        ContentType.objects.get_for_model(ParentResource).id
        }
    ),

                   url (
    regex = '^(?P<object_id>\d+)/child_resource/(?P<pk>\d+)/delete/$',
    view =  ChildResourceDeleteView.as_view(),
    name = 'parent_resource_child_resource_delete',
    kwargs={
        "content_type",
        ContentType.objects.get_for_model(ParentResource).id
        }
    ),
                   url (
    regex = '^(?P<object_id>\d+)/child_resource/(?P<pk>\d+)/edit/$',
    view =  ChildResourceUpdateView.as_view(),
    name = 'parent_resource_child_resource_update',
    kwargs={
        "content_type",
        ContentType.objects.get_for_model(ParentResource).id
        }
    ),
                   )
```

Edit:

The views Im using are inspired by [this](http://blog.headspin.com/?p=541) post

```
class ParentResourceMixin(object):
    model = ParentResource
    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('parent_resource_list')
    def get_queryset(self):
        return ParentResource.objects.all()


class ParentResourceListView(ParentResourceMixin, ListView):
    pass


class ParentResourceDetailView(ParentResourceMixin, DetailView):
    pass


class ParentResourceCreateView(ParentResourceMixin, CreateView):
    pass


class ParentResourceDeleteView(ParentResourceMixin, DeleteView):
    pass


class ParentResourceUpdateView(ParentResourceMixin, UpdateView):
    pass
```

Edit (solution based on jpic's answer):

The child resource views are:

```
class ChildResourceMixin(object):

    content_type = None

    model = ChildResource
    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('child_resource_list')
    def get_queryset(self):
        return ChildResource.objects.all()


class ChildResourceListView(ChildResourceMixin, ListView):
    pass


class ChildResourceDetailView(ChildResourceMixin, DetailView):
    pass


class ChildResourceCreateView(ChildResourceMixin, CreateView):
    pass


class ChildResourceDeleteView(ChildResourceMixin, DeleteView):
    pass


class ChildResourceUpdateView(ChildResourceMixin, UpdateView):
    pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CBV docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/#simple-usage-in-your-urlconf):

> If you’re only changing a few simple attributes on a class-based view, you can simply pass them into the as_view method call itself

```
ParentResourceListView.as_view(
    content_type=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(ParentResource).id)
```

For this to work, [you should define a class attribute](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.4/django/views/generic/base.py#L40), ie.

```
class ChildResourceMixin(object):
    content_type = None
```

This will enable argument passing from as_view().

I like what your code looks like, it looks simple and flexible.

Comment: Tried that, raises: `ParentResourceListView() received an invalid keyword 'content_type'`

Comment: Can you post source code for ParentResourceListView ? at least with method signatures. However, this works with django CBV, so you could also check their code and see how they get this to work.

Comment: Sorry I thought you figured it out by checking django's CBV source code. You've posted source for Parent* stuff, but your problem with the content_type argument is in the Child* stuff.

Comment: I figured, just set class attribute content_type=None, and [this should not raise an exception anymore](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/base.py#L55).

Comment: Also, I realised you develop `django-autocomplete-light` and `django-cities-light`. Ive just started using both. Thanks for the good work!